# Command line find if path matches and remove all contents

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to locate all folders that match a certain path.

The path is public_html/core/cache

I can find all instances of cache with the command below, however this does return results from elsewhere which are undesired!

```
find . -name cache -print
```

I've tried the below, but it presents an error.

```
find . -name public_html/core/cache -print
```

I'd like to run the script once to ensure the results are accurate, then afterwards run it again, removing all contents of the returned folder.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A kind friend gave me the solution:

```
find / -type d -path "*core/cache" -print
```